# Configuração electron js no windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

Estou estudando electron js e segui esse tutorial http://red-badger.com/blog/2016/04/18/building-desktop-apps-with-electron-webpack-and-redux/ porém no windows ocorre alguns erros. Primeiro dava erro por conta do enviroment no windows, eu consegui resolver isso mas depois começou outro problema pra rodar o script npm run dev estoura o seguinte erro(sei que ficou extenso):

```
electron-loja-desktop@1.0.0 dev C:\dev\repositorios\electron-loja-desktop
concurrently -k babel-node server.js npm start


Usage: npm 

where is one of:
access, add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c,
cache, completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag,
dist-tags, docs, edit, explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get,
help, help-search, home, i, info, init, install, issues, la,
link, list, ll, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner,
pack, ping, prefix, prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove,
repo, restart, rm, root, run-script, s, se, search, set,
show, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t, tag, team,
test, tst, un, uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up,
update, upgrade, v, version, view, whoami

npm -h quick help on 
npm -l display full usage info
npm faq commonly asked questions
npm help search for help on 
npm help npm involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
C:\Users\user\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@2.15.9 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
npm exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
server.js exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
babel-node exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
start exited with code 0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! electron-loja-desktop@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently -k babel-node server.js npm start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-loja-desktop@1.0.0 dev script 'concurrently -k babel-node server.js npm start'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the electron-loja-desktop package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! concurrently -k babel-node server.js npm start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR! npm bugs electron-loja-desktop
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm owner ls electron-loja-desktop
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! C:\dev\repositorios\electron-loja-desktop\npm-debug.log
```

Segue o link do repositório caso ajude:
https://github.com/guilhermegarcia86/electron-loja-desktop

Comment: Eu estava com o mesmo erro, resolveu pra mim desinstalar o nodejs e instalar suas dependências novamente. O electron é uma plataforma boa, mas eu não achei nenhum tutorial que possa sanar todas minhas duvidas, tente ler a documentação caso seu problema não seja resolvido reinstalando.